# Page with Ajax refreshes window title to be RGICLLayout3

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery

I don't know if this is typical, SharePoint related or soemthing else, but I'm finding that with some simple Ajax on a page, after the code has finished executing, the page/window title is 'RGICLLayout3'.

i.e. I have an .aspx page with title "My Site - my page", and on there I have some controls, one of which lazy loads using JavaScript/Ajax. When that control finishes loading, the window/page title changed from 'My Site - my page' to be 'RGICLLayout3'.

Anyone seen this before? Googling 'RGICLLayout3' shows zero results.

QMKevin

**[update]**
here some general code to explain what I'm doing:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnPreRender="up_PreRender">
<ContentTemplate>
    ...
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgressTab" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up"  >
 <ProgressTemplate>
    ...
 </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad(sender, e) {
    if (!e.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        __doPostBack('<%= up.ClientID %>', 'aaaa');
    }
}
</script>
```

and then in the codefile

```
    protected void up_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == up.ClientID && Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "aaaa")
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            upPanel.Visible = true;
            updProgressTab.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

This does what I need, mostly, but as I said, once the JavaScript force Postback is complete, the page title is changed. Hopefully this make my situation clearer, but ask for further clarification if needed.

Comment: When you say loads via Ajax, do you mean pure Ajax (just JavaScript) or using update panels?

Comment: Was a little rushed when I posted. Updated my question with code